# Form action problem

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a form for people to share an email on a page.  The forms pops up and users, in theory, can send an automated subject and message to a friend.  When I hit submit, however, the brower displays a 404, and I'm not sure why...

```
<div id="tellfriend" class="contact_form">
  <form id='tellafriend_form' method="post" action="#"  >

    <label for="name">Your Name: </label>
    <input class="std_input" type="text" id="name" name="name" size="40" maxlength="35" value="" />

    <label for="to">Friend's email: </label>
    <input class="std_input" type="text" id="to" name="to" size="40" maxlength="35" />

    <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
    <input class="std_input" type="text" id="subject" name="subject" size="40" value="subject line" />

    <label for="message">Message: </label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" readonly="readonly" rows="18" cols="40">message here</textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form_but" value="Submit"/>
  </form> 
</div><!-- #tellfriend -->
```

JS:

```
<script> 
$(function() {
    $('#tellfriend').hide();
    $('#sendMessage').click(function(e) {
        $("#tellfriend").fadeToggle('fast');
    });

});
</script>
```

site (bottom of the page): http://naturesfootprintinc.com/mjf

Comment: If it helps at all, it's based on this: http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/creating_a_tell-a-friend_pop-up_form_with_jquery_and_expressionengine/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form action is set to "#". You need to change it to some actual CGI page the browser can post to, like your page's URL if you're just trying to post back to that.

Comment: I've made this change (and I tried this previously), and I still get a 404.

Comment: check your server side code. it may be recieving your POST alright, but trying to return a file that isn't there.

Comment: It's a wordpress issue.  I was able to get it to redirect to a stylesheet, but it won't redirect to any wordpress pages.  Possibly a plugin or theme function issue.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `action = "#"` with the page where the data is processed or leave it blank so that the data is processed in the same page.